# Rewrite rules all variants of one main domain to another

Tags: wordpress

Say I'd like all traffic from one web domain to be redirected to another. Both sites are Wordpress sites. What's the best way to do this? By including rewrite rules in .htaccess?

For example - 
domain1.com/(anything) --> domain2.com
subdomain.domain1.com/(anything) --> domain2.com

If .htaccess, can someone give me some pointers as to what the rule might look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `RewriteRule`. You want to put this inside a `VirtualHost` block. Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName   domain1.com
    ServerAlias  *.domain1.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will take anything to the right of `domain1.com` and any subdomain of `domain1.com` and issue a `301 redirect` to `http://domain2.com/what/ever/path/was/requested`